# How to generate crash dumps for JNI code

Tags: java, java-native-interface, dump

everyone,

Suppose I have a simple JNI program in Windows:

```
int* p = NULL;
*p = 5;
```

When run it from JVM,  not like normal C++ application, JVM will nicely catch such hard exception and do some cleanup work.

The problem here is it also stops me from generating crash dumps right there, although there is a JVM option: -XX:OnError, but core dumps generated at this point is far from the crime scene thus hard to debug.

JVM wrap each Java thread using SEH:

```
__try
{
    thread.run()
}
__except(topLevelExceptionFilter())
{
}
```

JNI code which cause access violation happen in thread.run, but handled in topLevelExceptionFilter, which is already somewhere else.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `core` *is* a C++ crash dump... you don't have the convenience facilities that Java provides to make it easier to work with. If you compiled your native code to retain symbols (and ideally to not be optimized) you can use gdb or another debugger to analyze it and obtain a stack trace at the point of failure, as well as read variables, etc.

`core dumps generated at this point is far from the crime scene thus hard to debug` -- core dumps are not "far from the crime scene" at all, they're fully comprehensive of the so-called crime scene. The only reason you think they're hard to debug is it's something you haven't learned yet... but they're definitely the right tool for this job.

Comment: The point is JVM will catch such hard exception (access violation), thus you don't have the chance to generate core dump at the time of real error. The exception handling mechanism make the code execution jumps to the JVM's exception handler, that is where you get the core dump.

Comment: "Is it's something you haven't learned yet" - Could you provide more information on this? Thanks.

Comment: Actually the problem leading to the core dump must not be making it to the JVM's exception handler -- if it was, you could try/catch it. Core dumps occur when the OS detects a serious problem with the application and thus sends it a signal which is caught by the process's default signal handler rather than a custom signal handler... a custom handler could terminate the process without a core dump, or in some cases recover from it [through prior planning and the use of setjmp() and longjmp()].

Comment: `http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/linux/gdb-gnu-debugger-intro.php` has a tutorial to get started working with core dump analysis. Note though that if your native library is not compiled and linked with -g, the usefulness of your analysis will suffer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the OnError Setting to start a native Debugger, like so:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbmum

```
java -XX:OnError="gdb - %p" MyApplication
```

**For Windows**

There is also a `-XX:+ShowMessageBoxOnError` or `-XX:+UseOSErrorReporting` option for JDK7, not sure if it works for Linux core dumps, it should work for Windows and the default OS Debugger (DrWatson). See http://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/more_on_windows_crash_dumps

Comment: thanks, yea, the UseOSErrorReporting works in Windows; In linux, the coredump is generated as default, no need for additional option.

Answer (score 0):

In linux use ulimit - c unlimited to generate core dump
Then use gdb to debug core file with java process.